# RenderBody() and RenderSection() must be on every child layout?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

I have three simple layout,

**_Layout.cshtml** (this is the base layout)

```
@RenderSection("something", required: false)
@RenderBody()
```

**_Main.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section something {
   Hey I'm actually on the _Main layout.
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Main.cshtml";
}
```

When I try to render Index view in an action, I got this error,

> The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page
>   "~/Views/Shared/_Main.cshtml".

But wait, `_Main.cshtml` has a parent layout which already has a `RenderBody()`.
So am I wrong, must I call `RenderBody()` for every child layout?

Comment: @asymptoticFault, no it's just a mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use nested layouts like that.

Comment: Yes, you can nest layouts. Usually you can either have different inner layout pages or conditionally display content in your view.

Comment: Ah ok, hadn't tried that myself.

Comment: Because you are using _Main.cshtml as the layout page, you'll need to add RenderBody()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, RenderBody should be included on every layout page, regardless the nesting.

`@RenderBody` works as a placeholder for the engine to know where to drop the content of the view using the layout page.

Answer (score 7):

This code should work properly:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@RenderSection("something", required: false)
@RenderBody()
```

**_Main.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
@section something {
   Hey I'm actually on the _Main layout.
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Main.cshtml";
 }
<div id="Index Content Here">
 @RenderBody()
 </div>
```

#### index.cshtml should be rendered as per below:

```
<head>
Hey I'm actually on the _Main layout.   
</head>
 <div id="Index Content Here">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sections can be made optional by rendering them with `required: false`

```
@RenderSection("SectionName", required: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include section in last view.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Main.cshtml";
}

@section something {
    content
}
```

**UPDATE:** Okay, I fogot to say that you need also write @RenderSection in _Main layout

```
@section something {
    Hey I'm actually on the _Main layout.
    @RenderSection("something", required:false)
}
enter code here
```